# How do I prove that $p\to(q\wedge r)$ and $(p\to q)\wedge(p\to r)$ are logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Is it true that

1. p->(r ∧ q) is logically equivalent to (p->r) ∧ (p->q),
2. p->(r ∨ q) is logically equivalent to (p->r) ∨ (p->q)?

I am solving problems on logical arguments (check whether they are valid) and it would be easier if I could break down the statements above and check them seperately. I wrote the truth tables, which turned out to match, so I think they should be equivalent, but I am not sure.

Below are the truth tables that I used

[image: the truth tables]

Comment: Yes, because $p \to (r \land q)$ is equiv to $\lnot p \lor (r \land q)$ and thus you can apply "usual" distributivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also apply the properties of the logical operators involved:
\begin{align*}
(p\to(q\wedge r)) & \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee(q\wedge r))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee q)\wedge(\neg p\vee r)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (p\to q)\wedge(p\to r)
\end{align*}

Similarly, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
(p\to(q\vee r)) & \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee (q\vee r))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ((\neg p\vee\neg p)\vee(q\vee r))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee q)\vee(\neg p\vee r)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (p\to q)\vee(p\to r)
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a\rightarrow b = \lnot a \lor b$,

1. holds because $\lor$ distributes over $\land$
2. holds because $\lor$ is associative